No water coming through Lavazza Fantasia machine after descaling
I descaled my Lavazza Fantasia coffee machine and now no water is coming through.
I have checked the water tank.
I have run the steamer.
I have run the lungo option with no pod.
I have checked for any blockages... nothing obvious.
It is a few years old, but we only started using it 3 months ago...this was first descale.
Can you suggest anything else?

When you start the pump, do you hear it? Does the machine give any indication of turning on? What does happen when you start the machine? Also what kind of outlet is it plugged into? GFCI outlets can sometimes trip when you unplug appliances.
